# htaccess multiple rules and http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying figure out the rewrite rules. We currently have the following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|scripts)/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And we need an additional rule that redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

I've tried the following, but won't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|scripts)/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `L` flag to your redirect rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|scripts)/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @PeterFox it tells mod rewrite not to process any further rules, and since the request is flagged with a redirect, the rewrite engine will stop and respond with a redirect. Otherwise, the request is flagged with a redirect but without the `L`, will continue to execute the remaining rules (but will *still* have the redirect flag)

Comment: Thanks to clarifies it!